# Guzzlehttp Request method changed after sending when calling controller from Artisan Command

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, laravel-artisan, guzzle6

I am running into a weird issue -> I've got a controller set up to send a POST request to another application using GuzzleHttp - which works fine when this request is started from our VueJs client.

Now I am developing an Artisan Command (per request by the customer) to simplify calling this endpoint like 50+ times (as it generates videos) -> to call this endpoint I am using the following snippet as I am calling an internal controller:

```
$request = Request::create(
  route('videos.new', [], false),
  'POST',
  [
    // Some daata
  ]
);
$response = app()->handle($request);
$result = json_decode($response->getContent());
```

But the issue is, now the exact same code in that controller sends a `GET`  request instead of `POST` to the other application and I cannot figure out why as the method is HARD CODED in there.
I know it's a `GET` request as I am logging all requests entering the other application at the moment, url etc all looks correct, except that it's a `GET` request now

Request send with:

```
$cdnReq = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request(
  'POST',
  "/generate/$type?" . http_build_query($query),
  [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
  ],
  json_encode($input)
);
$this->beforeRequest($cdnReq);
// Step 03: Send request to cdn
Log::debug("Request(" . $cdnReq->getMethod() . ") will be send to: " . $client->getConfig('base_uri') . $cdnReq->getUri(), $input);
$cdnRes = $client->send($cdnReq);
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

INFO:
**Laravel Version:** Laravel/Framework 6.18.32

Comment: Putting the actual business logic into the controller is a bad practice. Calling the controller like that from the other part of your app is even worst. Why don't you extract the code to a job and reuse the job in both console command and in the controller.

Regarding your question I would investigate `$input` variable as it probably contains more than just required data.

Comment: The issue was related to an nginx_proxy running in-front of the application - so my POST got redirected to a GET request on HTTPS. I would love to refactor it into a separate job of sorts but I am not allowed too, there's no time and the project will be replaced with a new version without a few months -> so my only option is to mimic the VueJs client. ps: it all works now

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the URL being called as HTTP and redirected to HTTPS, which changes the POST to GET.